# How to "iron out" a column of numbers with duplicates in it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If one has the following column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"numbers":[1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7]})
```

How can one "iron" it out so that the duplicates become part of the series of numbers:

```
numbers  new_numbers
1        1
2        2 
3        3 
4        4
4        5 
5        6 

1        1
2        2 
2        3 
3        4
4        5 
5        6
6        7
7        8 
7        9     
8        10

1        1 
1        2  
2        3
2        4 
3        5 
4        6
5        7 
6        8
6        9
7        10
```

(I put spaces into the df for clarification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by `Series` created with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) and compare with [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html) (`<`) for finding starts of each group. Groups are made by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
#for better testing helper df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
df1['dif'] = df.numbers.diff()
df1['compare'] = df.numbers.diff().lt(0)
df1['groups'] = df.numbers.diff().lt(0).cumsum()
print (df1)
    dif compare  groups
0   NaN   False       0
1   1.0   False       0
2   1.0   False       0
3   1.0   False       0
4   0.0   False       0
5   1.0   False       0
6  -4.0    True       1
7   1.0   False       1
8   0.0   False       1
9   1.0   False       1
10  1.0   False       1
11  1.0   False       1
12  1.0   False       1
13  1.0   False       1
14  0.0   False       1
15  1.0   False       1
16 -7.0    True       2
17  0.0   False       2
18  1.0   False       2
19  0.0   False       2
20  1.0   False       2
21  1.0   False       2
22  1.0   False       2
23  1.0   False       2
24  0.0   False       2
25  1.0   False       2
```

```
df['new_numbers'] = df.groupby(df.numbers.diff().lt(0).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
print (df)
    numbers  new_numbers
0         1            1
1         2            2
2         3            3
3         4            4
4         4            5
5         5            6
6         1            1
7         2            2
8         2            3
9         3            4
10        4            5
11        5            6
12        6            7
13        7            8
14        7            9
15        8           10
16        1            1
17        1            2
18        2            3
19        2            4
20        3            5
21        4            6
22        5            7
23        6            8
24        6            9
25        7           10
```

Comment: Very clever, thank you. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could edit the question title to make it clearer? I dubbed the process "iron out".

Comment: My english is terrible, so hard give good advice. Maybe somthing like count by groups created by another column. But I am not sure if it is better, I feel it is still unclear. :(